# FFmpeg multi input and multi output

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, amazon-web-services, pulse-audio

I have been trying to collect audios from different pulse sources and x11grab video for merging some of them together. Finally all will be pushed to [AWS IVS](https://aws.amazon.com/ivs/)

This is the html for pushing audios to different devices. [My Html Codes](https://gist.github.com/yusufdealroom/4968c9ef1386f455a3bc71009f7198bc)

```
ffmpeg -y\
  -hide_banner -loglevel error \
  -nostdin \
  -s ${SCREEN_RESOLUTION} \
  -r ${VIDEO_FRAMERATE} \
  -draw_mouse 0 \
  -f x11grab \
    -i ${DISPLAY} \
    -f pulse -i MySink.monitor \
    -f pulse -i MySink2.monitor \
  -c:v libx264 \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -profile:v main \
    -preset veryfast \
    -x264opts "nal-hrd=cbr:no-scenecut" \
    -minrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -maxrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -g ${VIDEO_GOP} \
    -filter_complex \
    "adelay=delays=1000|1000;[1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=2[1_2]"\
    -map 0 0.mp4\
    -map 2 2.flv \
    -map 0 -map 1 0_1.mp4 \
    -map 0 -map 2 0_2.mp4 \
    -map 0:v -map "[1_2]":a:0 -f flv ${RTMP_URL1}\
    -map 0:v -map 1:a:0 -f flv ${RTMP_URL2}\
```

**Above code push to IVS but video is blank and no audio**.

```
    -filter_complex \
    "adelay=delays=1000|1000"\
    -f flv ${RTMP_URL1}\
```

When I remove maps and just push to rtmp like above, video is working just with audio 0 which is wrong.
**I guess problem is map with rtmp. How can I use them together?**

**Second Question:**
If I use "[1_2]" again it gives me:

> Output with label '1_2' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere

So splited like below

```
    -filter_complex \
    "adelay=delays=1000|1000;[1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=2[1_2];split [main][tmp];"\
    -map 0:v -map "[main]":a:0 -f flv ${RTMP_URL1}\
    -map 0:v -map "[tmp]":a:0 -f flv 0_1_2.flv\
```

then this error got

> No such filter: ''

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue so maybe somebody can need it.
Below solution not that much performant because of many times encoding

`````
ffmpeg -y\
  -hide_banner -loglevel error \
  -nostdin \
  -s ${SCREEN_RESOLUTION} \
  -r ${VIDEO_FRAMERATE} \
  -draw_mouse 0 \
  -f x11grab \
    -i ${DISPLAY} \
  -f pulse -i MySink1.monitor \
  -f pulse -i MySink2.monitor \
  -f pulse -i MySink3.monitor \
  -f pulse -i MySink4.monitor \
  -c:v libx264 \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -profile:v main \
    -preset veryfast \
    -minrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -maxrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -g ${VIDEO_GOP} \
    -map 0 -f flv -map 1  ${RTMP_URL1} \
  -c:v libx264 \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -profile:v main \
    -preset veryfast \
    -minrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -maxrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -g ${VIDEO_GOP} \
    -map 0 -f flv -map 2  ${RTMP_URL2} \
  -c:v libx264 \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -profile:v main \
    -preset veryfast \
    -minrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -maxrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -g ${VIDEO_GOP} \
    -map 0 -f flv -map 3  ${RTMP_URL3} \
  -c:v libx264 \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -profile:v main \
    -preset veryfast \
    -minrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -maxrate ${VIDEO_BITRATE} \
    -g ${VIDEO_GOP} \
    -map 0 -f flv -map 4  ${RTMP_URL4} \

    ````
`````